# CSS transition issue in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari, cross-browser, webkit

This fails in safari. Tested ok in chrome, opera and firefox.

When hover over a div(1) a child div(2) slides by modifying left property.

This second div contains child elements(buttons) that flicker not following with the slide transition of its parent div(2).

```
**username:Alex
**password:passwordAlex
```

Example by accessing Users page:

http://monkey-me.herokuapp.com/users

complete CSS:

https://github.com/coolcatDev/monkey-me-heroku/blob/master/static/css/style.css

Reference of divs:

```
**div(1)->class .contentUser
**div(2)->class .contentButtonWrap
**child buttons of div(2)->class .contentButton
```

Comment: Seems that everything is working as expected in Safari 8 on OS X. Which Safari version did you used for testing?

Comment: @mcj I'm on Version 5.1.10

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following as part of style of the element suffering the transition(div 2) solved it:

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

The bug occurs without this property in both safari 5.1.10 and 6